# React JS Testing Ajax using Mocha & Sinon

Tags: ajax, testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

In a React application I want to test an ajax call

A click event is handled by a method:

```
_search = () => {
    AppActions.search({
      url: this.props.url,
      queryValue: query
    })
  }
```

and this invokes a method on a store which makes an Ajax call:

```
onSearch (req) {
    $.get(url)
      .done((data) => {
        // set state...
      })
  }
```

I was trying to use Sinon to stub the jquery ajax call:

```
describe('Search', function () {
  describe('Rendering', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.stub($, 'ajax')
      let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MockComponent />)
      this.renderedDOM = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
      $.ajax.restore()
    })

    it('Should make an ajax request', () => {
      TestUtils.Simulate.click(myButton)
      // expect stubbed ajax call to have been made with args etc
    })
  })
})
```

Anyone know how I should do this so that I can:

1. stub the ajax call
2. invoke a callback or
3. inspect the stubbed ajax call

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use sinon's fakeServer api.

for example:

```
const server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith("GET", "/rest/api/yourURL", [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, '{"response": "whatever"}']);

// TODO: test code

server.respond();
server.restore();
```

It can stub the ajax call and invoke a callback